# Swift KVO - Observing enum properties

Tags: swift, enums, key-value-observing

I'm assembling a class which has several states, as defined by an enum, and a read-only property "state" which returns the instance's current state.  I was hoping to use KVO techniques to observe changes in state but this doesn't seem possible:

`dynamic var state:ItemState  // Generates compile-time error: Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

I guess I could represent each state as an Int or String, etc. but is there a simple alternative workaround that would preserve the type safety that the enum would otherwise provide?

Vince.

Comment: Regarding this old question, these days ***simply mark the enum as an Int*** and you're good to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I came across the same problem a while ago.
In the end I used an enum for the state and added an additional 'raw' property which is set by a property observer on the main state property.

You can KVO the 'raw' property but then reference the real enum property when it changes.

It's obviously a bit of a hack but for me it was better than ditching the enum altogether and losing all the benefits.

eg.

```
class Model : NSObject {

    enum AnEnumType : String {
        case STATE_A = "A"
        case STATE_B = "B"
    }

    dynamic private(set) var enumTypeStateRaw : String?

    var enumTypeState : AnEnumType? {
        didSet {
            enumTypeStateRaw = enumTypeState?.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

ADDITIONAL:

If you are writing the classes that are doing the observing in Swift here's a handy utility class to take some of the pain away.
The benefits are:

1. no need for your observer to subclass NSObject.
2. observation callback code as a closure rather than having to implement
   observeValueForKeyPath:BlahBlah...
3. no need to make sure you removeObserver, it's taken care of for you.

The utility class is called `KVOObserver` and an example usage is:

```
class ExampleObserver {

    let model : Model
    private var modelStateKvoObserver : KVOObserver?

    init(model : Model) {

        self.model = model

        modelStateKvoObserver = KVOObserver.observe(model, keyPath: "enumTypeStateRaw") { [unowned self] in
            println("new state = \(self.model.enumTypeState)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note `[unowned self]` in the capture list to avoid reference cycle.

Here's `KVOObserver`...

```
class KVOObserver: NSObject {

    private let callback: ()->Void
    private let observee: NSObject
    private let keyPath: String

    private init(observee: NSObject, keyPath : String, callback: ()->Void) {
        self.callback = callback
        self.observee = observee
        self.keyPath = keyPath;
    }

    deinit {
        println("KVOObserver deinit")
        observee.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String,
        ofObject object: AnyObject,
        change: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        context: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) {
            println("KVOObserver: observeValueForKey: \(keyPath), \(object)")
            self.callback()
    }

    class func observe(object: NSObject, keyPath : String, callback: ()->Void) -> KVOObserver {
        let kvoObserver = KVOObserver(observee: object, keyPath: keyPath, callback: callback)
        object.addObserver(kvoObserver, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
        return kvoObserver
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Works nicely.  Use the raw value to just detect a change but reference the enum, rather than the raw, to determine the new state.  I wouldn't have though of that.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Took me a while to arrive at that solution! One thing to note: you can't use it if your enum raw values are Int and you want your property to be Optional, since you can't have an Int? property as dynamic.

Comment: Although, you could convert to NSNumber? I guess.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem in this case; since these objects will always have a state, it need never be optional.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan are you observing with a Swift class?

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan if so I've just added a handy utility class to my answer that you might find useful.

Comment: That's an excellent helper class.  It simplifies some of the cruft that comes with implementing KVO, so I've incorporated it into my app.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MikePollard, what if I have Enum cases with arguments? Can that be observed through your solution?

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps this is only available in swift 2+, but you can make an enum property directly observable without having to refer to its rawValue.  It does come with some limitations however.

1. have the containing class extend from `NSObject` (directly or indirectly)
2. mark the enum with `@objc`
3. extend the enum from `Int`
4. declare the property as `dynamic`.

```
class SomeModel : NSObject {                          // (1) extend from NSObject
    @objc                                             // (2) mark enum with @objc
    enum ItemState : Int, CustomStringConvertible {   // (3) extend enum from Int
        case Ready, Set, Go

        // implementing CustomStringConvertible for example output
        var description : String {
            switch self {
            case .Ready: return "Ready"
            case .Set: return "Set"
            case .Go: return "Go"
            }
        }
    }

    dynamic var state = ItemState.Ready               // (4) declare property as dynamic
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
class EnumObserverExample : NSObject {
    private let _model : SomeModel

    init(model:SomeModel) {
        _model = model
        super.init()
        _model.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"state", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
    }
    deinit {
        _model.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"state", context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if "state" == keyPath {
            print("Observed state change to \(_model.state)")
        }
    }
}

let model = SomeModel()
let observer = EnumObserverExample(model:model)
model.state = .Set
model.state = .Go
```

Outputs:

```
Observed state change to Ready    (because .Initial was specified)
Observed state change to Set
Observed state change to Go
```

Comment: Thanks! For me it worked with simply making sure the enum is `Int` and has `@objc` in front of it. Very neat.

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the best answer. Publicly exposing both enum and raw value doesn't look neat, especially when it can be avoided.

Comment: This is (today) by far the correct answer.  It's a good example of where good but old answers on SO simply become wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great.